# iTextSharp convert to pdf .net Tiles are not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, tiff

I am trying to read the `TIFF` file from the disk and converting to `PDF` format using `iTextSharp`

It works fine, but except some `TIFF` which got some image into it. Getting error like `Tiles are not supported` error at this line `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(documentPath)`

Here is the code I use

```
string documentPath="somefile.TIFF";

try
{
  Image myImage = Image.GetInstance(documentPath); //Error here     
  documentPDF.Add(myImage);
  byte[] bytes= ms.GetBuffer();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Error says tiles are not supported
}
```

**StackTrace:**

> at
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.GetTiffImage(RandomAccessFileOrArray
>   s, Int32 page, Boolean direct)    at
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.GetTiffImage(RandomAccessFileOrArray
>   s, Int32 page)    at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url)    at
>   iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(String filename)

Could someone help me to fix this? Is this fixed in new version?

After looking the code **[here](http://www.opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/itextsharp/TiffImage.cs.html)**, seems they check for Tiles thatpresent in TIFF.

**Is there any pdf creator from reading TIFF with Tiles for C#?**

Comment: are you running the above code in a loop?

Comment: @Sudhakar, No. its not in a loop. Just opening only a single document

Comment: You edited the same as I have suggested. Well done my friend. You are a good learner.

Comment: A couple of ideas: try to convert the tiff or pass through System.Drawing.Image using  GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image image,

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can create PDFs from tiled TIFFs and other popular formats, too.

Here is a sample code that creates a PDF from an image (tiled TIFF or not). The image is scaled to fit into page.

```
public static void createPdfFromImage(string imageFile, string output)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument())
    {
        PdfImage img = doc.AddImage(imageFile);

        PdfPage page = doc.Pages[0];
        double widthRatio = (double)page.Width / (double)img.Width;
        double heightRatio = (double)page.Height / (double)img.Height;
        double ratio = Math.Min(Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio), 1);

        page.Canvas.DrawImage(img, 0, 0,
            (float)(img.Width * ratio), (float)(img.Height * ratio), 0f);

        doc.Save(output);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Comment: Is it open source and free for dev/commercial use?

Comment: @Billa it's neither free nor open source.